# Macro to consolidate data and paste after last row

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a macro that will consolidate data from 2 sheets and paste them in a new sheet one after another. I'm having problem with the second part of my code.

I'm getting an

> application or object defined error.

I think the range might be an issue - I want to copy all the used rows of column D from the Dump sheet and paste them after the last used row in column K in the Summary sheet. This is what I have so far

```
Sub Paste()
    Dim lRow3 As Long
    Dim rng3 As Range

    With ThisWorkbook
        With .Sheets("Dump Lease & RMP Charges")
            lRow3 = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rng3 = .Range("D3:D" & lRow3)
            rng3.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary Invoice ex").Range("K6")
        End With

        With Sheets("Dump MMS Service and Repairs")
            .Range(.Range("D3").End(xlToRight)).Copy 'line with error
        End With

        With Sheets("Summary Invoice ex")
            .Cells(.Rows.count, "K").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

I changed the last part to

```
 With .Sheets("Dump MMS Service and Repairs")
    lRow4 = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng4 = .Range("D3:D" & lRow4)
    rng4.Copy Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Summary Invoice ex").Cells(lRow4 + 1, "K")

 End With
```

Now there is no error but nothing is pasting!

Comment: Beyond anything else: `.Range(.Range("D3").End(xlToRight)).Copy` is the same as `.Range("D3").End(xlToRight).Copy` - was there supposed to be a second corner to your Range?

Comment: I removed the second .range, but I'm still getting the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To copy all used rows in column D outgoing from cell D3 try

```
.Range(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp), .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)).Copy
```

instead of your error throwing line `.Range(.Range("D3").End(xlToRight)).Copy` in your original code.

**How it works:**

- `.Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)` finds the last used row in column D
- `.Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)` finds the last used column in row 3

`.Range` makes a range of these two cells.

---

**Edit accordingly the comment:**
To copy rows in column D only use …

```
.Range("D3", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).Copy
```

Comment: So the code works, but it copied every column after D and pasted all of them in K

Comment: So you only want all rows in column D then?

Comment: Yes, all the used cells of column D

Comment: @Leena see my edit. This copies from D3 to last used cell in column D

Answer (score -1):

An Application or Object defined error. Generally means there is a typo somewhere.

Your second with statement has a bullet point.

```
With .Sheets("Dump Lease & RMP Charges")
```

Should it not be

```
With Sheets("Dump Lease & RMP Charges")
```

Hopefully this gets rid of the Application/object error.

Comment: There definitely should be a period in front of `Sheets`. The 3rd and 4th `With` statements are also missing periods.

Comment: The period means that `.Sheets` refers to `ThisWorkbook` of the outer `With` block `With ThisWorkbook`. So it totally correct to use `With .Sheets("Dump Lease & RMP Charges")` even if nested `With` blocks are not best practice.

Comment: Yeah, so it was the other way around. Couldn't remember if it was with or without.